# PyTroch, Gradient calculations

Tags: pytorch, gradient

https://colab.research.google.com/github/pytorch/tutorials/blob/gh-pages/_downloads/neural_networks_tutorial.ipynb

Hi I am trying to understand the NN with pytorch. 
I have doubts in gradient calculations..

import torch.optim as optim

````
create your optimizer
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)


```
# in your training loop:
optimizer.zero_grad()   # zero the gradient buffers
output = net(input)
loss = criterion(output, target)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()    # Does the update
```
````

From the about code, I understood loss.backward() calculates the gradients. 
I am not sure, how these info shared with `optimizer` to update the gradient.

Can anyone explain this..

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The gradients are attached to the variables that are inside your model (accessed with a call to `net.parameters()`). When you call `loss.backward()`, these gradients are populated. As your optimiser knows about the parameters from `optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)`, it can simply go ahead and access each parameter and its corresponding gradient and apply them.

Answer (score 2):

When you created the optimizer in this line

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

You provided `net.parameters()` with all learnable parameters that will be updated, based on gradients.

The model and the optimizer are connected only because they share the same parameters.

PyTorch parameters are tensors. They are not called variables anymore.